# What is the Excel formula to extract only the numbers from a percentage figure?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel 2016 and I have the following figures in an Excel worksheet:

```
 A       B     
23%   22.9566%
 1%   0.61253%
 5%   4.7461%
```

I want Column C to show the following:

```
 C
 23
  1
  5
```

Col B is showing the values of Col A with 4 decimal places.
What would be the Excel formula that will allow me to extract the exact numbers showing in column A?

Notes: 
(1) Excel functions that I have tried and didn't work: INT, TRUNC, ROUND

(2) Columns A and B are formatted as "Percentage"

Comment: tried `ROUND` and worked just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INT((A1*100)+0.5)
```

If you want it as a percentage then divide it all by 100

Comment: Or alternatively =ROUND(A1*100,0)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!